# Twitter Bootstrap base CSS

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I want to put a form in my site I use base form codes from bootstrap official site but view of getbootstrap.com  is very different than my view(Especially button and input view very different from the site )

HTML:

```
<form>
                        <fieldset>
                          <legend>dfhadfhahhf</legend>
                          <label>isim</label>
                          <input type="text" placeholder="Type something…">
                        </fieldset><br>
                         <fieldset>
                          <label>isim</label>
                          <input type="text" placeholder="Type something…">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
                        </fieldset>
                        <!-- Form -->
                      </form>
```

By the way I have all components of bootstrap:

```
<link href="static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

where is the problem? :(

Comment: What do you mean by different? Create a jsfiddle if you can.

Comment: Can you give us screen shots of what you want compared to what you are seeing? Off the top of my head I know Bootstrap often uses more than just two CSS links...

Comment: if you have skype account I can share my screen there

Comment: Your missing some class names see my answer below

Comment: Bootstrap.css applies css to elements with certain class names, you don't have any of those classes for your elements. Simon has the right idea. You could also look on the bootstrap site and copy their examples for more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your missing some class names etc try something like

```
  <form role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <legend>dfhadfhahhf</legend>
        <label>isim</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Type something…" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <br>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label>isim</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Type something…" class="form-control">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </div>
         <!-- Form -->
  </form>
```

for instance :

```
  <form role="form">
```

and swopped your fieldset for:

```
  <div class="form-group">
```

etc

Comment: yeah that's true answer I already solve by myself :) thanks for helping